# How to make tool windows remember their monitor and position in IntelliJ Idea 13

Tags: intellij-idea

How to make tool windows remember their monitor and position in IntelliJ Idea 13?

Is there a way to do that?

I have 2 monitors with different resolutions.

I like to keep the main window of the IDE (and the code editor) on my laptop monitor and have the tool windows (Debug, Changes, Run, Terminal, Maven) on the second one at max width and height.

So What I do is to float them, max them on the second monitor and pin them there.

it works but every time I close the IDE, or sometimes during my day they get back to the main monitor again.

They kind of maintain their height and width (a few pixels less I think) but they appear huge in the middle of my smaller monitor.

This is the only draw back I have to say agains the IDE, and in Eclipse this kind of thing works as a charm.

Is there a way to solve it? Or a plugin?

Cheers

Comment: Which system? I am doing the same for my documentation tab and it works (floating+pinned). Except for the missing "maximize". Win8+IDEA13.

Comment: The worst one is the Debug window. it always resets to the Primary display... I noticed that if I don't use the "hide window" feature. They tend to stay there at least during the current session.

Comment: Now I'm curious. I tested it with several restarts, but works with my IDEA 13.1.3. Maybe a different setup, I set the Debug window to floating+pinned yet there is no "hide window" in the popup.

Comment: I do the exact same thing. Floating+pinned. and it always reset position to center when Idea closes. I will take a look to see if it's one of my plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Find window. Solution was to close IDEA (13.1.5) with all windows positioned as I like. It seems IDEA memorizes window positions only on termination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and today I found this in jetbrains help website:

### Save the arrangement of tool windows﻿:

From the main menu, select Window | Store Current Layout as Default.

the url is: [Arrange tool windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#save-layout)